# How do I resolve the value of a databinding inside a MarkupExtension?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, markup-extensions

I've made a markup extension for translating strings based on a key. Example

```
<TextBlock Text="{Translate myKey}" />
```

Now I want to be able to use nested bindings for providing my keys. Example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Translate {Binding KeyFromDataContext}}" />
```

When I do this I get a System.Windows.Data.Binding object. By calling ProvideValue and passing down the ServiceProvider I can get a BindingExpression:

```
var binding = Key as Binding;
if (binding == null) {
    return null;
}
var bindingExpression = binding.ProvideValue(_serviceProvider) as BindingExpression;
if (bindingExpression == null) {
    return null;
}
var bindingKey = bindingExpression.DataItem;
```

I can get this bindingExpression, but the DataItem property is null. I've tested my binding like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyFromDataContext}" />
```

and it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MarkupExtension that uses a DataBinding value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737126/markupextension-that-uses-a-databinding-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [toxvaerd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006448/332528) is not universal. It breaks if the original binding already had a converter. Or when writing a converter is not possible.

There's a better solution. We can declare two constructors. The second one accepting `BindingBase` will be called by XAML when a binding is used. To resolve the value of the binding, we can declare a private attached property. For this to work we need to know the target element of the markup extension.

There's a catch: when the markup extension is used inside a template, there is no target element (obviously). In this case you are [supposed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a9ead3d5-a4e4-4f9c-b507-b7a7d530c6a9/gaining-access-to-target-object-instead-of-shareddp-in-custom-markupextensions-providevalue-method?forum=wpf) to use `return this` in `ProvideValue()` - this way the extension will be called again when the template is applied.

```
public class TranslateExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly BindingBase _binding;

    public TranslateExtension(BindingBase binding)
    {
        _binding = binding;
    }

    public TranslateExtension(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (_binding != null)
        {
            var pvt = (IProvideValueTarget)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget));
            var target = pvt.TargetObject as DependencyObject;

            // if we are inside a template, WPF will call us again when it is applied
            if (target == null)
                return this; 

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(target, ValueProperty, _binding);
            Key = (string)target.GetValue(ValueProperty);
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(target, ValueProperty);
        }

        // now do the translation using Key
        return ...;
    }

    private static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(string), typeof(TranslateExtension));
}
```

Comment: What if the binding value changes, ProvideValue doesn't get called again right? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Haitam the question was about resolving the value of the binding. If you suspect it might change - you can instead return another binding that binds to `Value` and uses a converter.

Comment: Can you, please, explain how the attached property here works? I am always getting `null` from `target.GetValue()` ...

Comment: @spacer your binding itself is probably wrong. Post a minimal example as a separate question please.

Comment: torvin, my original binding works fine, I got it to work with [ygoe's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737126/markupextension-that-uses-a-databinding-value). I don't have time to post a new question at the moment, might do it when I revisit this.

Comment: While this may somehow have worked by accident, it is not at all a general solution. For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69684897/1136211

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** possible to get the value of a binding. You're not supposed to be even trying to do this. WPF uses some fancy reflection to resolve the bindings and trust me - you do not wan't to start trying that yourself.

Anyway with that in mind, this is what I ended up doing, which actually is a nice solution:

I made a `TranslateConverter` that took care of the translation:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var key = value as string ?? parameter as string;

    if (key != null)
    {
    // Do translation based on the key

    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in my `TranslateExtension` I simply do this:

```
var binding = Key as Binding ?? new Binding{Mode = BindingMode.OneWay};
binding.Converter = new TranslateConverter(_targetObject, _targetProperty, Dictionary, Converter);
binding.ConverterParameter = Key is Binding ? null : Key as string;

return binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
```

This way a binding is resolved by WPF and is passed to the converter as value, while a simple text-key is passed to the converter as a paramter.

`_targetObject` and `_targetProperty` are obtained from the ServiceProvider.

Comment: What does that mean? A data binding's one and only use it to transport a value and keep it up-to-date. How can a binding not have a value then? I'm looking for the same solution but you didn't answer your question, you answered something else. A converter is not an option for me.