# Current binding value

Tags: wpf, binding, markup-extensions

I'm writing markup extension. I have XAML like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{ui:Test SomeInfo}" />
```

and TestExtension with constructor taking one string argument. I'm getting "SomeInfo" string so everything is find. Now I want to nest extensions and write something like

```
<TextBlock Text="{ui:Test {Binding PropName}}" />
```

and it does not work as is. I had to add constructor which takes one argument of System.Windows.Data.Binding type.

Now I need to know

1. How should I retrieve a current value from the Binding object?
2. When should I do this? Should I subscribe to changes some way or ask for that value every time in ProvideValue method?

---

**Update1** PropName should be resolved against DataContext of TextBlock.

**Update2** Just found related question: [How do I resolve the value of a databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985902/how-do-i-resolve-the-value-of-a-databinding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bindings like this will not work because your `MarkupExtension` has no `DataContext` and it does not appear in the visual tree and i do not think you are supposed to interact with binding objects directly. Do you really need this extension? Maybe you could make do with the binding alone and a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx)?

If not you ***could*** create a dedicated class which has bindable properties (by inheriting from `DependencyObject`), this however would still not give you a `DataContext` or namescope needed for `ElementName` or a visual tree needed for `RelativeSource`, so the only way to make a binding work in that situation is by using a `Source` (e.g. set it to a `StaticResource`). This is hardly ideal.

Also note that if you do not directly set a binding the `ProvideValue` method will only be called once, this means that even if you have a binding in your extension it may not prove very useful (with some exceptions, e.g. when returning complex content, like e.g. an `ItemsControl` which uses the binding, but you set the extension on `TextBlock.Text` which is just a string), so i really doubt that you want to use a MarkupExtension like this if the value should change dynamically based on the binding. As noted earlier: Consider [converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) or [MultiBindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) for various values instead.

Comment: Actually, I want to use DataContext of Textblock.

Comment: @adontz: As i said, you are probably better off using a normal Binding with a converter, getting the bindings inside your own MarkupExtension to work is a pain.

Comment: I accept this pain, because it provides markup users with more consistent syntax which is important for me.

Comment: @adontz: What exactly does the MarkupExtension *do* and how is the syntax supposed to be more consistent, if you go with keeping your markup-extension you will have to use element syntax, like: `<TextBlock.Text><ui:Test><!-- Set properties here --></ui:Test></TextBlock.Text>`, it's gonna blow things up and to get to the DataContext you may need to define parts in resources, it's almost certainly not worth it.

Comment: My point is not to use some specific approach, like markup extension, but to support some specific syntax, like the one I already posted in the first message - "{ui:Test {Binding PropName}}". Syntax you're talking about is not acceptable. I see no reason why my task is impossible.

Comment: @adontz: From a binding you can get a `BindingExpression` using `ProvideValue`, but that is where it stops as far as i know. Everything beyond that is internal to the WPF's binding engine, you cannot completely resolve the binding yourself. And as i explained MarkupExtensions lack about everything needed for bindings on themselves, they are not bindable objects.