# How is a markup extension method applied to a binding value in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, markup-extensions

I have a localization markup extension method for strings, which I can apply in this way:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{l:Translate 'My string'}" />
```

How can I apply this markup extension method to the result of a binding? I.e. something like that:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{l:Translate '{Binding Path=myStringParameter}'}" />
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it with a converter? Or you can use a _MarkupExtension_.

Comment: No, because the Translate method does a little bit more, than just replace the string. Ah, I just realized that I misstyped, it's a markup extension, not a string extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a markup extention just do this:

```
{l:Translate {Binding Path=myStringParameter}}
```

The XAML parser will handle the inner markup extention itself. Like in classical WPF: `{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}`

Comment: Ah, my problem then is with the markup extension: Its constructor accepts a string and no bindings. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: After getting the binding, getting the value is not easily possible. Look here for further proceedings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985902/how-do-i-resolve-the-value-of-a-databinding?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible the way you do it, but you can rewrite its as follows:

```
 <TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Text>
        <l:Translate>
           <Binding Path="myStringParameter" />
        </l:Translate>
     </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```