# How can I build a Binding Markup Extension that translates text?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, internationalization

I am rewriting a Delphi 7 application in WPF. One requirement is that all labels, headings, messages etc. are translatable to another language. I am required to use the existing in-house translation engine, versus .NET i18n using resources.

I would very much like to extend the `Binding` markup extension to be able to specify the language the resultant string is in. This will only be for one way binding, e.g. a simple {"Binding NameLabel Lang=Twi"} so the label for the Name field is displayed in Twi.

I'm sure I can inherit from the binding object, and override some method to call the translation service (through Service Locator} just before it delivers the value asked for from the data context.

Comment: Something like [this](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @user3411327 Yes, that looks ideal, but also looks heavily dependent on resource files, which my employer wants to avoid creating in favour of their existing dictionary code.

Comment: You can plug in your own [localization provider](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Localization%20providers&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: @user3411327 That looks great, but the latest version of that interface has an undocumented `GetFullyQualifiedResourceKey` method, with only `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090008/332528)

Answer (score 0):

You can derived from `Binding` but **you can't override the behaviour** to change the returned value i.e. you can't intercept the code in between **because `ProvideValue` method is marked as sealed in BindingBase class** so you can't override it and change in derived class.

Definition in BindingBase:

```
public override sealed object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);
```

---

But in case you interested in custom markup extension which will return i18n string, you can do this way:

```
public class CustomBinding : MarkupExtension
{
    public string Lang { get; set; }

    public static object GetValue(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetValue(ValueProperty);
    }

    public static void SetValue(DependencyObject obj, Binding value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Value", typeof(object), 
                                             typeof(CustomBinding));        


    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget pvt = serviceProvider as IProvideValueTarget;
        DependencyObject targetObject = pvt.TargetObject as DependencyObject;

        if (targetObject == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        string value = GetValue(targetObject).ToString();
        // You get the bound value here. Put i18n code here
        // and return actual value. (Access Lang property to get the culture)
        return value;
    }
}
```

As you can see i have declare attached property instead of normal DP because for that you have to derive from DependencyObject but we are already deriving from MarkupExtension so can't do multiple inheritance. Have to settle with attached property to provide binding support from XAML.

**Usage in XAML:**

```
<TextBlock local:CustomBinding.Value="{Binding PropertyName}"
           Text="{local:CustomBinding Lang=Twi}"/>
```

Of course you have to define `local` namespace in XAML.

Comment: I'll give it a try. It looks like it will work just fine, except for the name `Value`, which some elements may already have. I'll attach `LocalText` or something. Thanks.